# Passing Parameters to Action Functions in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I created tableView cells with an action and I need the action to know the indexPath of the cell that is selected. I can't figure out how to pass the indexPath as a parameter to the action or find any other way around it. Here is the code for the tableView cellForRowAt and the action to be performed:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "menuCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.foodName.text = self.menuItems[indexPath.row]
    //adding gesture recognizer with action Tap to cell
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(Tap(gesture:index:IndexPath.row)))
    cell.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    return cell
}

func Tap(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer , index: Int){
    print("Tap")
    //necessary so that the page does not open twice
    //adding the rating view
    let ratingVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "rating") as! RatingView
    ratingVC.foodName = selectedItem
    self.addChildViewController(ratingVC)
    ratingVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
    self.view.addSubview(ratingVC.view)
    ratingVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}
```

I can't figure out how to pass the IndexPath.row as a parameter to Tap.

Comment: If you provide the ability to select only one row in the tableView, you can use the `indexPathForSelectedRow` property in `fund Tap`  to get the current selected row's indexPath. For further details on the property, check  [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1615000-indexpathforselectedrow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to do the functionality of selecting the cell, [UITableViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate) already has this kind of behaviour.

By conforming to [UITableViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate) and implementing [tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614877-tableview) method, you will be able to get the `indexPath.row` for the selected cell:

> Tells the delegate that the specified row is now selected

So, after implementing `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` you should get rid of `tapGesture` functionality, it should be similar to:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "menuCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.foodName.text = self.menuItems[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("Selected row: \(indexPath.row)")
}
```

Comment: I do have that functionality elsewhere in the class. The problem is I am trying to open up a separate page when a cell is tapped and the contents of that page depends on which cell is tapped.

Comment: You can implement this inside `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` method, I assume that you do recognize the selected cell based on what is the indexPath.row

Comment: Thank you this is the functionality I was looking for! Can't believe I didn't think of that

Comment: Welcome :) Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Use didSelectRowAt Indexpath method.

For custom Tap use following steps.

1. Assign tag to your cell.

   let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tapBlurButton(_:)))

   ```
   cell.tag = indexPath.row  
   cell.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
   ```

2.Manage tap event

```
func tapBlurButton(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
   //Get indexpath.row value or Indexpath Value
print(sender.view.tag)

}
```

Hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the tap gesture. Second implement the `didSelectRow` delegate of the `tableView` like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
//add your rating view code here
let ratingVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "rating") as! RatingView
ratingVC.foodName = self.menuItems[indexPath.row] //get the selected item
self.addChildViewController(ratingVC)
ratingVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
self.view.addSubview(ratingVC.view)
ratingVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

}

Of course, you will want to add checks and guards to make sure you catch any errors.